# How to treat first character different when appending same string variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a string dynamically with the names of all items separated by comma.

```
var itemName = '';
for (var i=0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
    itemName = itemName+","+itemArray[i].name;
}
```

Suppose, I have 3 items with name - `Shoe, Jeans & Shirt`. I want variable itemName to be saved as `Shoe,Jeans,Shirt`

Below is itemArray

```
[{"name":"shoe","size":"3","brand":"lee"},{"name":"Jeans","size":"5","brand":"le‌​e"}...]
```

When I do using above code it will come like this `,Shoe,Jeans,Shirt`

What is the effective method to avoid first comma ?

Is there any method in JavaScript similar to `${stat.first?'':','}` in jstl ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add the `,` char after the first item has been written into variable and don't write the `,` char on the last element of the iterating array

```
itemArray = [
                 {
                     "name" : "shoe",
                     "size" : "3",
                     "brand" : "lee"
                 }, {
                     "name" : "Jeans",
                     "size" : "5",
                    "brand" : "le‌​‌​e"
                 }
              ];

var itemName = '';
var sSeparator = ',';
var i;
for(i=0; i<itemArray.length; i+=1){

   itemName += itemArray[i].name;

   if(i < itemArray.length - 1){
       itemName += sSeparator;
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include an explanation of what was wrong in the original code - that helps sigificantly.

Comment: join and map is made for this.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Note: `Array.map` is ECMA5, but there are polyfils available.

Javascript

```
var itemArray = [{
        name: "Shoe"
    }, {
        name: "Jeans"
    }, {
        name: "Shirt"
    }],
    itemName = itemArray.map(function (item) {
        return item.name;
    }).join(",");

console.log(itemName);
```

Output

```
Shoe,Jeans,Shirt
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7eUye/)

Comment: itemArray is as below 
[{"name":"shoe";"size":"3";"brand":"lee"},{"name":"Jeans";"size":"5";"brand":"le‌​e"}...]

Comment: Ah yes I can see that now, it was not clear in your original question and you should have included that information.

Comment: @RaheebM your itemArray looks wrong...Must be  itemArray = [{
                "name" : "shoe",
                "size" : "3",
                "brand" : "lee"
            }, {
                "name" : "Jeans",
                "size" : "5",
                "brand" : "le‌​‌​e"
            }];

Comment: @Bernhard: or  `[{"name":"shoe","size":"3","brand":"lee"},{"name":"Jeans","size":"5","brand":"le‌​‌​e"}]`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to tackle this problem.

**Way 1:** Do what you're doing. Just remember to remove the first character of the string:

```
function join(array, delimiter, name) {
    var index = 0, length = array.length, string = "";
    while (index < length) string += delimiter + array[index++][name];
    return string.slice(1);
}
```

**Way 2:** Essentially this solution is the same as the first one. However it makes use of `map` and `join`:

```
function join(array, delimiter, name) {
    return array.map(function (item) {
        return item[name];
    }).join(delimiter);
}
```

The first way is faster than the second. However the second way is more readable. Either way you can now do what you want by simply calling `join` as follows:

```
join(itemArray, ",", "name");
```

Hope that helps.